# Plotting beam pattern of uniform linear array

Tags: matlab, beamforming, array-signal-processing

I am trying to reproduce Fig. 2.17 from the book 'Optimum Array Processing' by Van Trees.

[image]

The figure is a polar plot of the beam pattern $B_{\theta}(\theta)$ given by

$$B_{\theta}(\theta) = \frac{1}{N}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{N}{2} \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\, \cos(\theta) \,d\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} \,\cos(\theta) \,d\right)}$$

with $d = \frac{\lambda}{2}$ and $N = 11$ elements. The MATLAB code I have written is as follows:

```
N = 11; % no. of array elements

th = 0:0.01:2*pi; % theta

B = 1/N*sin(N/2*pi*cos(th))./sin(1/2*pi*cos(th)); 
BdB = 20*log10(abs(B));

figure
polarplot(th, BdB);
rlim([-40 max(BdB)]);
```

I am unable to reproduce the figure. I believe there are two reasons:

1. The spacing between elements in `th`, equal to 0.01, is probably not appropriate. How do we set it?
2. The axis limits on the polar plot, as given in `rlim()`, should be such that all the lobes converge at the center of the plot. How should we decide these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pretty close, just a few cosmetics will get you there.

1. Your angle resolution isn't quite high enough to hit all the narrow dips in the polar pattern. I increased it to 1000 points.
2. You need to clip the level data at the lower plotting limit (-40dB). Otherwise `polarplot()` will calculate a negative radius which will poke out on the opposite side of the plot.
3. You can use `polaraxes()` to flavor your plot to whatever you want.

This looks pretty close to me. It has level ticks at 0 degrees and not a -90 degrees but in my opinion that's easier to read and you can move it with `pax.RAxisLocation = -90` if you want. It also has negative angles on the left side, which is (in my opinion) "correct".

[image]

```
%% Polarplot example
N = 11; % no. of array elements

% MOD1: do a finer resoltion and go from -pi to +pi
n = 1000; % number of points
dTheta = 2*pi/n;
th = -pi:dTheta:pi; % theta

B = 1/N*sin(N/2*pi*cos(th))./sin(1/2*pi*cos(th)); 
BdB = 20*log10(abs(B));
% MOD2: cut off the data at the lowest disaply value.
BdB(BdB<-40) = -40;

figure(1); clf
pax = polaraxes;
polarplot(th, BdB);
rlim([-40 max(BdB)]);
% MOD3: Match angle location and direction.
pax.ThetaZeroLocation = 'top';
pax.ThetaDir = 'clockwise';
pax.ThetaLim = [-180 180];
% set line color and width
h = get(gca,'Children');
set(h,'LineWidth',2,'Color',[0 0 0]);
```